# An onto map to a Unit Circle $|z|=1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers

An onto map from the critical line $$\frac{1}{2}+it , t\in \mathbb{R}$$ to the unit circle $$|z|=1$$

My try-
$$z=  \frac{\frac{1}{2}+it}{\frac{1}{2}-it} $$
$$|z|=1$$
But the map is not onto $z=-1$ is not attained

Comment: Well, you don't need it to be one-to-one, right?  So multiple values could map to the same point on the circle, yes?

Comment: @Brian Tung Right. Please give a map.

Comment: A continuous bijection is impossible because one is compact and the other is not. I would start with the same map you did. If you don't need 1-to-1, then apply Brian Tung's suggestion. Like square what you have.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen I could not get you. Please write as an answer. I will give you check mark

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Please answer.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen means that you should square the expression you currently have for $z$ (in terms of $t$).

Comment: Also, this is probably a language issue (at least in part), but "Please give a map" sounds like a command in English (even with the "please").  A better wording—that is, one less likely to be received negatively—would be "Could you help me construct a map?"

Comment: @Brian Tung I squared the expression but could not find an Onto map. Could you please help me construct a map?

Comment: @Brian Tung Please help me with the map

Comment: Did someone help you with the map you already have, $z = (1/2 + it)/(1/2 - it)$?  If you understand that one, you should be able to square the right-hand side to arrive at a suitable map.

Comment: Based on your other questions, I suspect your confusions are more fundamental than this question, and might better be resolved in real time with, for example, your professor.  Be sure that you understand clearly what a map is, and what "onto" (that is, surjective) means.

Comment: @shekharsuman Try this: Define $f(z)=z-1/2$ for $z\in \mathbb C.$ Then $e^{f(1/2+it)} = e^{(1/2+it)-1/2} = e^{it}.$ Thus $e^{f(1/2+it)}$ maps your line onto the unit circle.

Comment: @zhw. Thanks. So our map is from which set to which set? What is the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f: t \mapsto e^{it}$ is an onto map from $\mathbb R$ to the unit circle. $g : \frac 12 + it \mapsto t$ is a bijective map from the critical line to $\mathbb R$. Their composition $f \circ g$ will be the function you're looking for.

Comment: Please give me an explicit map. I could not understand.

Comment: @martism Please define a map  from critical line to unit circle.

Comment: $f \circ g$ is a map from the critical line to the unit circle. I have given $f$ explicitly and $g$ can be effortlessly converted into an explicit expression as well. You should have no trouble writing $f \circ g$ explicitly either

Comment: please write fog explicitly.

Comment: please answer. I will give your answer a check mark.

Comment: $g$ becomes $t \mapsto \frac{t - \frac 12}{i} = \frac 12 i - ti$, so if we compose it with $f$, we get $t \mapsto e^{i (\frac 12 i - ti)} = e^{t - \frac 12}$

Comment: but $e^{t-1/2}$ is not on the unit circle.

Comment: if $t$ is on the critical line, then $e^{t - \frac 12}$ is on the unit circle

Comment: I have given you a check mark. Please answer this simple question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4039164/prove-that-oint-c0-1fzdz-oint-d0-1-fzdz#