# Prove that $\oint _{C(0,1)}f(z)dz= \oint _{ D(0,1) }f(z)dz $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

Define $C(0,1)= \{z: \mid z\mid=1 \}$
$D(0,1)= \{z: \mid z\mid=1, z\neq 1+0i \}$

Prove that,
$$\oint _{C(0,1)}f(z)dz= \oint _{ D(0,1)
  }f(z)dz  $$
**My try**

$z=1+0i$ is of measure zero. So, $$\oint _{C(0,1)}f(z)dz= \oint _{ D(0,1)
  }f(z)dz  $$

Comment: ...why would anyone ask you such a silly question?

Comment: @Joshua P. Swanson So the two integrals are equal?

Comment: Of course. Changing the integrand on a set of measure zero does nothing to the integral, as you've essentially already noted. You could write the second integral as using the integrand $g(z) := f(z) 1_{z \neq 1}$ where $1_{z \neq 1}$ is $1$ if $z \neq 1$ and is $0$ if $z = 1$.

Comment: @Joshua P. Swanson Please write as an answer.

Comment: @Joshua P. Swanson But Fred  considers f as continuous for both integrals being equal.

Comment: As I said, continuity is not relevant. I do not know why he brought it up. All you'd need is integrability, but that's tacitly assumed whenever you write an integral. Anyway, when you're doing contour integrals you're almost always far from such pathologies, making the whole thing silly.

Comment: @Joshua P. Swanson Ok so continuity is not needed???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course. Changing the integrand on a set of measure zero does nothing to the integral, as you've essentially already noted. You could write the second integral as using the integrand $g(z) := f(z) 1_{z \neq 1}$ where $1_{z \neq 1}$ is $1$ if $z \neq 1$ and is $0$ if $z = 1$.

Comment: How is the integral of f(z) and g(z) the same?

Comment: How are the two integrals same. Please give a proof.

Comment: Please give an explanation as to how these are equal.

Comment: Please reply . I am convinced and will give you a check mark.

Comment: The other guy deleted his answer. Please explain your answer. It is very important for my grad.

Comment: Is my answer correct?

Comment: Why the Downvotes?

Comment: Why the downvotes??

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you've been pretty insistent, demanding, and entitled. You need to remember you're asking random strangers to help you out of the goodness of their hearts. This reply I'm typing here is a courtesy you probably wouldn't get from most people. Also, the question itself is just pretty silly and is lacking context. It's something like asking "why is 1+1+0=1+1?" It just is, and you'd have to start giving your definition of the basic terms involved if you wanted to really break it down, and you'd need to convince people it's worth their time to answer.

Comment: Please tell me if my answer is correct.

Answer (score -1):

Since $$e^{i\theta}=1 \Rightarrow \theta=0,2\pi $$
$$\oint _{ D(0,1) }f(z)dz =\int_{[0,2\pi]-  \{0,2\pi\} } ie^{i\theta}f(e^{i\theta})d\theta $$
Since $\{0,2\pi\} $ is a set of measure 0
$$\oint _{ D(0,1) }f(z)dz =\int_{0}^{2\pi} ie^{i\theta}f(e^{i\theta})d\theta $$
$$\oint _{ D(0,1) }f(z)dz =\oint _{ C(0,1) }f(z)dz$$